Difference between the case where net force is zero and when no force is acting
I read online that the difference between the two cases is that the body deforms, but what if the body is perfectly rigid would there be another way to diffrentiate between the two cases? if not then I have a problem, suppose we have a body ascending in a gravitional field with uniform velocity, for a rigid body this should be equivalent to no force acting case hence no work will be done but this is clearly wrong since dropping the body would release energy and the body would accelerate. So there has to be other ways an observer could diffrentiate between the two cases.

What are you trying to differentiate here? Its unclear. A helicopter hovering can be modeled with no net forces acting on it vertically. A ball thrown into the air will have no net forces on the vertical axis for a moment as it reaches its apex. By eliminating plastic or elastic deformation, you essentially eliminate a consideration for differentiation as well. Also, to maintain a uniform velocity ascending in a gravitational field, the forces will be changing as the gravitational field is not uniform.

I am trying to diffrentiate between scenario where there are forces acting but 0 net force and a case where there are no forces acting.Are they equivelant because if they are then that wouldn't make sense as it would imply(I guess) that a non existent force is doing work or a force that exists does 0 work(I am saying that since both scenarios are equivelant  they must be interchangeable) , but I guess they would never be equivelant even if the bodies are non-deformable because the scenarios just diffrentiate themselves by saying there are forces present in one but not the other.

"By eliminating plastic or elastic deformation, you essentially eliminate a consideration for differentiation" yes that is the reason is said that so one can't diffrentiate between both cases from the deformation of the body.

"the forces will be changing as the gravitational field is not uniform" I can assume that the field is uniform for sake of simplicity I can exchange the gravitational force for any force


... what if the body is perfectly rigid - would there be another way to differentiate between the two cases ?

Yes. If two equal and opposite forces act on the body, but do not act along the same line then they create a non-zero couple and the body will rotate. Similarly if three or more forces act on the body, even if they net to zero, they may create a non-zero couple and so cause the body to rotate.

Okay what if they act along the same line of action

@Johngreg If the net force is zero and the couple is zero and the body is rigid then this is identical at a given moment to no force acting at all. Of course, if you take away one of the forces then you have created a difference - which is what is happening in your example of dropping an object.

Okay, but during that moment where the body is  ascending at constant velocity it is definitely not true that there is no work is done ,would this be the way an observer could tell the difference between the two cases

@Johngreg If you know a force is acting on the body then you can infer that it is doing work, and if you know that work is being done then you can infer that there is a force. But this is a circular argument. If you don't know that a force is acting on the body then you have no independent way of telling whether work is being done or not.

Right I think the scenarios are already different since I specified that the forces are present


but what if the body is perfectly rigid would there be another way to
diffrentiate between the two cases?

Yes, if there is a change in angular velocity of the rigid body. That can happen if the net force on the body is zero, but not the net torque.

suppose we have a body ascending in a gravitional field with uniform
velocity, for a rigid body this should be equivalent to no force
acting case hence no work will be done

If by "velocity" you mean both uniform translational and angular velocity, then both the net force and net torque on the body would be zero. But just because the net force is zero, doesn't mean no work is being done. It means no net work is done.
The force that is raising the object is doing positive work while the force of gravity, which acts opposite to the direction of motion, is doing an equal amount of negative work for a net work of zero.  In so doing, gravity takes the energy given the body by the lifting force and stores it as gravitational potential energy in the Earth-body system.
Of course if the body is simply released, then, ignoring air resistance, net work is done by force of gravity. The positive work done by gravity increases the kinetic energy of the body while decreasing the gravitational potential energy of the Earth-body system by an equal amount.

Okay but what I meant with giving the gravity and force model is that
both cases are equivelant or not because if they were then work should
be zero or a force thay doesn't exist does work which is wrong

They are equivalent in that the both result in zero acceleration. No work is being done if there is no force. Although if the net force is zero no net work is done, the forces involved are individually doing work that is equal in magnitude but opposite in sign.
Hope this helps.

Okay but what I meant with giving the gravity and force model is that both cases are equivelant or not because if they were then work should be zero or a force thay doesn't exist does work which is wrong

@Johngreg see update to my answer.

Okay I think I am not being clear enough. If the two situations are equivelant where there are forces acting but the net force is 0 and the othere situation is where there are no forces acting if the body is rigid and they don't cause torque when those forces act on the body ,shouldn't they have same effect as the forces not existing ,but that would mean either a non existent force does non zero work or a force acting over a distance does zero work.I know individual forces do work even if there net is 0 but if both situations are equivelant then a contradiction appears .

@Johngreg Regarding the beginning of your comment the two situations are not equivalent since in one case forces are doing work (though the net work is zero) while in the other no work is being done. After that, I'm sorry but I can't make sense of the rest.

So would this be a way of inferring the inequivalence of the two situations(I mean work is done hence a force must be present)

@Johngreg It depends on what you mean by equivalence. They are equivalent in that no net work is done and no acceleration is produced. But they are not equivalent in that individual forces are doing work (and the sources of those forces are either expending energy or acquiring energy).

If no force is acting on a moving body, then no external system is gaining or losing energy in the form of work.
In contrast, if a pair of equal and opposite forces is acting on the body (with some degree of alignment with the direction of motion), then the motion is the same, but the source of one force is gaining energy, and the source of the other force is losing energy. This distinguishes the two cases.

When you pick up a small ball between your thumb and index finger, and then hold it in place above the ground, is your thumb gaining energy and index finger losing energy? Or is it vice versa?

There’s no energy transferred when pushing against a motionless object.

This answer needs further clarity. "if a pair of equal and opposite forces is acting on the body (with some degree of alignment with the direction of motion), then the motion is the same, but the source of one force is gaining energy, and the source of the other force is losing energy." and "There’s no energy transferred when pushing against a motionless object." need to be reconciled. Expand your answer to be clearer.

What’s to be reconciled? The answer is about a moving object,  as described in the original question. I’ve also addressed your question about a motionless object.

Net work is different from the individual work done by an individual conservative force like gravity.
Net work gives you the change in kinetic energy (which of course is zero in your example).
The work done by the gravitational force alone is the negative of the change in gravitational potential energy, which is non-zero in your example:
$$
W_{\textrm{by grav, on obj}} = \int d\vec r\cdot \vec {F}_{grav} = -\int dU_{grav} = mgh_1 - mgh_2
$$
As part of your problem statement, you asserted that the object is rising with a constant velocity, so there must be an additional force (or forces) acting on the object. The net force is equal to  the sum of those other forces $\vec F_{\textrm{other}}$ plus the force due to gravity. Thus we have:
$$
\vec {F}_{net} = \vec F_{\textrm{other}}+\vec{F}_{grav}
$$
and
$$
W_{net} = \int d\vec r\cdot \vec {F}_{net} = K_2 - K_1 = 0
$$
